# Dynamically include XML files using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, dynamic, include

I am trying to merge multiple XML files into one in the following manner:

Say I have an XML file, called `fruit.xml`:

```
<fruit>
    <apples>
        <include ref="apples.xml" />
    </apples>
    <bananas>
        <include ref="bananas.xml" />
    </bananas>
    <oranges>
        <include ref="oranges.xml" />
    </oranges>
</fruit>
```

and subsequent XML files that are referenced from `fruit.xml`, like for example `apples.xml`:

```
<fruit>
    <apples>
        <apple type="jonagold" color="red" />
        <... />
    </apples>
</fruit>
```

and so on... I would like to merge these into 1 XML file, like such:

```
<fruit>
    <apples>
        <apple type="jonagold" color="red" />
        <... />
    </apples>
    <bananas>
        <banana type="chiquita" color="yellow" />
        <... />
    </bananas>
    <oranges>
        <orange type="some-orange-type" color="orange" />
        <... />
    </oranges>
</fruit>
```

I want to determine the "child" files (like `apples.xml`, `bananas.xml`, etc.) dynamically based on the values of the `ref` attributes in the `<include>` elements of `fruits.xml` and then include them in the output.

**Is this possible using XSLT?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the contend of an file should be included you can use:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document(@ref)/fruit/*/*"/>
```

Therefore try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="include">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document(@ref)/fruit/*/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I am now trying to make it process `<include>` elements in subsequent files as well, like so:
    `<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)/fruit/*/*/*"/></xsl:copy>` instead of `<xsl:copy-of ... />` but the result is `<include><include><banana .../></include></include>`. Any tips?

Comment: Cancel that, already fixed it: I removed the `<copy>` element inside the `<template match="include">` altoghether!

Comment: If you have to look at specific elements in your included files you can perhaps use applytemplates