# In XSLT, is it possible to keep track of the path and use it dynamically?

Tags: xslt, dynamic, path

Yesterday I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671472/dynamically-include-xml-files-using-xslt) about loading external XMLs dynamically from XSLTs. It was answered, but now I have another problem. If you read that question you'll see an `<include ref="/path/to/some.xml" />` at the third level. What if the level at which the `<include>` occurs varies?

Is there a way to dynamically choose to extract the nodes from that XML on the same level on which they occur in the original file?

**EDIT:**
To be clear: I'm talking about the "element path" in the XML (the position of the include element in the XML), not the file path.

merge.xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="include">
      <!-- the depth of the extraction path (fruit/*/*/*... etc) should
           be based on the position of the matched <include> element -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@ref)/fruit/*/*/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

fruit.xml:

```
<fruit>
  <local>
    <apples>
      <include ref="apples.xml" />
    </apples>
  </local>
  <exotic>
    <bananas>
      <deeperlevel>
        <include ref="bananas.xml" />
      </deeperlevel>
    </bananas>
    <oranges>
      <include ref="oranges.xml" />
    </oranges>
  </exotic>
</fruit>
```

bananans.xml:

```
<fruit>
  <exotic>
    <bananas>
      <deeperlevel>
        <banana type="chiquita" color="yellow" />
        <banana type="generic" color="yellow" />
      </deeperlevel>
    </bananas>
  </exotic>
</fruit>
```

result:

```
<fruit>
  <local>
    <apples>
      <apple type="jonagold" color="red"/><apple type="granny-smith" color="green"/>
    </apples>
  </local>
  <exotic>
    <bananas>
      <deeperlevel>
        <deeperlevel> <!-- I don't want the second <deeperlevel> here, instead
                           <bananas .../> should be extracted, right after the
                           first <deeperlevel> -->
          <banana type="chiquita" color="yellow"/>
          <banana type="generic" color="yellow"/>
        </deeperlevel>
      </deeperlevel>
    </bananas>
    <oranges>
      <orange type="juice-orange" color="orange"/><orange type="red-orange" color="red"/>
    </oranges>
  </exotic>
</fruit>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the number of steps in the `ref` attribute value (i.e. `/path/to/some.xml`) when referring to levels? Or are you talking about the position of `include` elements? In the latter case the suggested solution should work, it simply matches any `include` element, independent of the nesting level it occurs in. You might want to post a new XML input sample and the result you want to explain to us which additional requirements you face.

Comment: I edited my question, it's about the selection of the element that is extracted from the external XML document, they already end up at the correct position in the output XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem. It's not extremely nice IMHO, because it's an "eval"-type solution, but it works. I applied the 3rd suggestion in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630023/dynamic-xpath-in-xslt) to my problem, the dynamic XPath evaluation extension (`dyn:evaluate()`). Luckily the `xsltproc` tool from the `libxslt` library (installed through macports, version 1.1.27) supports it.

I am going to leave the question open for a while, maybe someone has a better solution.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
  extension-element-prefixes="dyn">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:param name="depth" select="'/*'" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="concat($depth, '/*')" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="include">
    <xsl:param name="depth" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dyn:evaluate(concat('document(@ref)', $depth))">
      <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```